# Tomcat's time problem when app inserts records in DB

Tags: tomcat, time

I have an apache 2 web server working with a tomcat 6 servlet container running on ununtu 9.1, integrated via mod_proxy.

I have the following time mismatch problem:

- When apache log to its access-log
  file, the date/time is correct.
- When a grails app  running on tomcat inserts date-related
  information in the DB, the time is three
  hours ahead

Any tips on how to fix tomcat's datetime problem ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this a Timezone problem?  Perhaps setting up the TZ variable (and exporting it) in the tomcat startup script might help.

Answer (score 0):

GO to Catalina.sh File and Set the Time Zone. It may mismatch with the System. LIke -Duser.timezone=GMT+5 add this into JAVA_OPT Variable.

Comment: This is such an ugly solution.